# Getting jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm a total noob to flask. I'm just getting started with flask and jinja template engine.
Please, kindly answer me.
This is my html head tag,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% if {{content}} %}
    <title>WAJ - {{content}}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>WAJ</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
```

The content variable is a string passed from flask,
But I'm getting this error

```
 File "d:\python programs\Flask Project\templates\user.html", line 6, in template
    {% if {{content}} %}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

I tried re-reading the code and checked for what could have gone wrong. But didn't find a solution. please help.

Comment: `{% if content %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the issue in your code is simple. You don't need double curly braces {{ }} inside the {% if %} block.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        {% if content %}
            <title>WAJ - {{ content }}</title>
        {% else %}
            <title>WAJ</title>
        {% endif %}
    </head>
```

Just replace the {{content}} with content and you are good to go.
I would like to give you a nice little suggestion since you are a newbie, that is... Whenever you get a syntax error or something like that, you should look up to the documentation. It is a good habit that every programmer should adopt.
Links to the documentations:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/templating/

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my error. Also sure, I'll check out the documentation. Thanks for the suggestion!